# Initializing class member in UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Class is derived from Control in Asp.Net C#.

Public class member is defined as:

```
    public bool isPresent = true;
```

Then in Render method check is performed :

```
    if (isPresent)
       doSomething;
```

On a form this field is set to false:

```
    <c:CustomControl id="CustomControl1" isPresent="false">
```

When this code is executed locally from VS, everything is fine. Being deployed to the server, however, throws exception for the line with check for "if (isPresent)", saying that object reference is not set.

At the same time, if this line is changed to be "if (isPresent == true)", everything is fine both locally and on the server.

Is setting of value for class member of the Control different when run from VS and from IIS? Is it initialized in IIS before comparison operation, and not before implicit check?

UPDATE: as has been correctly pointed, this variable is a field, not a property. There is no other class member (and no property with same name).

UPDATE2: in addition, if check for value being not null is added, there is no exception anymore. Can it be the case that object initializer sets value of the field in case of explicit comparison operation?

```
    if (isPresent == null)
       return;
    if (isPresent)
       doSomething;
```

Comment: The other strange thing to me is that "isPresent" is a boolean, which if I'm correct should not get a null reference exception

Comment: `public bool isPresent = true;` is not a `Property`, it is a `Field`.  Properties will have a `get` and `set` method.  AFAIK you cannot set a field from an ASP.NET server control attribute like you have proposed here, so I'm surprised that it works at all.

Comment: @CodingGorilla THat was my thought, so why could he get "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on that line?

Comment: I think, that because the c:CustomControl includes a Property, but there exists a field by the same name, that maybe the run-time is getting confused?

Comment: @DanDrews yea, you are correct that should not be possible - I suspect there's something missing here.  Even if, as Les suggests, there's a real property which we are not seeing, that still wouldn't cause a NRE in referencing a boolean field, since a boolean can never be null (unless it's `bool?`).

Comment: Probably object initializer tries to set property via reflection, by name and object don't exist. Because it is public member and not property

Comment: @T.S. That sounds plausible, but the NRE, according to the OP, occurs at the `if(isPresent)` line.  Doesn't make sense - maybe the OP can post some more code so we have a better picture as to what's going on.

Comment: The other comment that I would make is that if you look at the IL that is generated from the code: `if(isPresent) { ... }` and from: `if(isPresent == true) { ... }`, I would suspect that the IL is identical.  Meaning that functionally the two statements are processed identically.

Comment: @CodingGorilla: thank you very much for your help. I was thinking that these 2 statements are identical, but the behavior on server varies; while locally both work. There is no more code to it. Any ideas?

Comment: @bonafiden I would love to see a small project with identical code that can reproduce this, because honestly I don't know how this is even possible.  Maybe there's just something goofy with that specific server, can you reproduce on another server?

Answer (score 1):

When creating user controls, the most advisable manner to store property values is in the View State, as follows:

```
public bool IsPresent
{
    get 
    {
        bool isPresent = false;
        if (ViewState["IsPresent"] != null)
        {
            isPresent = (bool) ViewState["IsPresent"];
        }
        return isPresent;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["IsPresent"] = value;
    }
}
```

Then, the control would be declared as follows (Note that the IsPresent starts with Upper I):

```
<c:CustomControl id="CustomControl1" IsPresent="false">
```

Whenever storing data on controls, keep in mind that they must be persisted on the page. If you simply declare a variable, there is no guarantee that the data will hold between requests. The only manner to make sure the data is persisted, is to save it in the View State. You can find support to these statements [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1408664.aspx?ASP%20NET%20Custom%20attributes%20on%20a%20server%20control) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s70936s.aspx).

The question of why the behavior changes in the IIS and Visual Studio may be not relevant here because simply declaring a variable, as stated above, provides no assurance at all that the data will be saved.

Regarding the Property being a getter/setter, note that it must be declared as shown above, in order to the property to be recognized by the ASPX page.

Comment: thank you for the advice. However, the question remains: why 2 statements above behave differently on the server? What is the explanation?

Comment: Updated the question. Please, see if the answer makes you happy :)

Comment: thank you for further explanation :-) I got what you said about Property/getter/setter and ViewState. However, the goal of the question is to understand why with what is now in the code, statement iwth explicit comparison works, and statement with implicit comparison invokes NRE?

Comment: I really think there may not be a good explanation for that, because since you have no guarantee that the value is persisted, the behavior may be random. It may be working like this in your environment, but in some place else this might change. That's the point I am trying to make: there may be no reasonable answer to that question.

Comment: there is no need to persist value of isPresent; it should serve as one-time parameter intended only for Render method - to inform how to render the control, and that's it.

Comment: Think of the following scenario: you put your control in the page and you submit the page, getting back to it (make a postback). If the value is not in the view state you loose its value. Moreover, every control in .NET persists its values in the view state. So your custom control should do the same.

Comment: In order to support what I am saying, check the links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s70936s.aspx and http://forums.asp.net/t/1408664.aspx?ASP+NET+Custom+attributes+on+a+server+control

Comment: Thank you. Agreed in case of postbacks. However, this is case of simple page with text without postbacks. Still need an answer to root question.

Comment: @EduardoFernandes You are incorrect when you say that because there is "no persistence" the effect would be random.  The control is still a class and follows all the normal class instantiation rules, and since this is a _field_ with an initialization value, and further this is a value type, it **can never be null** and should **never* be able to produce a NRE under any circumstances.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, in the links I provided, everytime a property is defined for user controls, it is stored in the view state. Creating a class does not ensure the data will be persisted, because you are in a web application and in the end data is either persisted in the client or in the server side. The point is, simply creating elements in a class does not mean it will be safely saved, otherwise you would not need view state in your code-behind. If what you are saying were true, everytime you need to save data you would simply have to create properties, in the code-behind or any other place.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, I do get your point about the null bool, and I cannot give an explanation for that neither. I believe it may have to do with autoboxing in .NET. I also had similar problems when they were all sorted out when I properly stored the values.